# Bonita project can't run when mapping own form to process

Tags: javascript, java, platform, bonita

I am new at Bonita platform, currently adding form to process.

When I add form to process pool I get error:
error while resolving form mapping process.... The target bonita form with Id null does not exist.

When I set it to default form, it works correctly, but adding my created form creates this error.

Everything is created from this tutorial:
https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/2022.1/getting-started/create-web-user-interfaces

Any help?

See picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwBB4.png